# Publishing ready laravel project on bitbucket

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, bitbucket

So my test project on laravel 5.4 has come to its end and my future employer wants me to post my project on bitbucket repository. So, the question is: how can I publish my project for my employer, so he could work with it and check it?

I want to know which files I should post. I got local DB with products catalogue, used tinker to fill it; for migrations I used Artisan, and composer also works in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bitbucket account and add your employer to your repository. You should learn more about git.

If you want your employer to review your code before, work on a different branch and create a pull request for your employer when you commit your code. Your employer can then review the code and can merge the branch to master.

Comment: Already made it. But I want to know which files I need to put in it

Comment: Don't commit your .env file or node_modules directory.

Your project must have a .gitignore file which will tell git to exclude those files. The .gitignore file is present by default in any laravel installation. Unless you messed with it, you are good to commit all the files to the repository.

Comment: So, if this file will be included, it'll post important project files to git? I understood it right?

Comment: .env is only for local. You'll be storing your database passwords, auth keys, tokens, etc. It is not a good practise to commit .env to a repo. Check if your project has a .gitignore file, if it exists you are good to go. Also see what files and directories are being ignored.